# JQuery UI sortable is slow in IE8, but works good in IE7 and IE8 compatible mode

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, internet-explorer-8

JQuery UI sortable (including demos) are slow in all IE8 I can test, but runs smoothly in IE7 and IE8 compatible mode. The more complex is a markup on the page, the more IE8 is slowing down (that's I can understand, the DOM tree became more complex).

I'm using JQuery 1.3.2 and JQuery UI 1.7.2 (tested with 1.7.3 -- the same story).

I've found a lot of similar reports (for the new JQuery UI 1.8.x with JQuery 1.4 too), but no answers.

May be there is a some solution (EXCEPT turning IE8 into IE7 compatibility mode by metatag or header). Thanks in advance!

Comment: It seems like most of the UI is slow in IE8 (comparatively), even on their demo site.

Comment: The demos are quite simple, but when placed inside complex document it became really slow... :(

Comment: God knows what the IE developers actually did! 'Cos they sure as hell werent making it standards compliant or fast.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you figured some solution out by now, but just in case others are reading this.  I think the answer is upgrade to jQuery 1.4 and jQuery UI 1.8.  These are significantly faster than their predecessors.

For sites where you have dependencies on jQuery 1.3, you may be able to get by with upgrading to 1.4 and using the backwards compatibility plugin:

https://github.com/jquery/jquery-compat-1.3

Comment: Unfortunatelly I haven't found the answer yet. And the site in question I can't upgrade to latest jQueryUI because of other (not mine) dependencies.

Comment: Hm, that's unfortunate.  One thing you could try is switching to jQuery 1.4 and then adding the backward compatibility plugin:

https://github.com/jquery/jquery-compat-1.3

I've had mixed results with this technique in the past, but it's worth a try.  Oh, and try just the jQuery upgrade before you attempt the jQuery UI upgrade, not sure if UI 1.8 works with the compat plugin.